# How can I connect to MySQL from Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, centos

I am trying to create a login page for a website using perl CGI. In an already existing script the database handle is `connect("DBI:mysql")`

When I run the command
$ `mysql -u root -p`

The linux server shows command not found.

I am new to modules DBI and CGI in perl. So i am confused if mysql does not exist on the linux how should i create a database and connect to it using DBI?

Comment: Could the database be on another server?

Comment: `mysql`, the MySQL client, apparently needs to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

There could well be many steps to get through here in order to get this all working.

But, question one is: which platform are you running on? Your command prompt makes me think it's Linux, but which distribution and which version of that distribution.

It looks very much like you don't have the MySQL client packages installed. The easiest way to do that will depend on your answer to question one.

On a Debian-based system (which includes Ubuntu), you can run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

On a RedHat-based system (which includes things like Fedora and Centos), you can run:

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-client
```

If that last command tells you that `yum` can't be found, then try:

```
$ sudo dnf install mysql-client
```

Once you have the client installed, we can move on to the next step :-)

Comment: it is centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.x86_64 so I will use yum install.

Comment: I have SQLite on the server. Should I install the SQLite client packages instead?

Comment: @Callie: Well that depends. Is the requirement to set up and connect to a new database (in which case, SQLite could be an option) or do you need to connect to an existing MySQL database (in which case, you'll need the MySQL libraries).